# 2012 Dodge Grand Caravan Rear Hatch Not Opening All the Way

Tags: grand-caravan, rear-end

My rear hatch is not opening all the way. When it goes up it stops at almost the top and the it jolts back down until it closes. It acts like something is blocking it from opening all the way. Any suggestions of what might be causing this?

Comment: Is there anything on the struts?

Comment: Is there resistance when pulling it open?

Comment: Nothing on struts and no resistance when opening.

Comment: I am going to try to replace the lift supports and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the lift rods for the hatch and it fixed the problem. Took less then 10 minutes to change them out.

Comment: Yay!  Glad you found a fix!  Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair, by the way!